# How to know which HTML/.js file (and line of file if possible) included another .js file? Firebug somehow?

Tags: javascript, html, firebug

So I'm debugging some code at work that I didn't write, and I'm having trouble understanding why in Firefox I have additional .js files loaded than I do in Chrome.

After scouring the code I can't seem to locate where these .js files are being included.  I'm wondering if this is something Firebug can tell me or if another add-on or another method entirely can come to the rescue.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox can trigger a breakpoint on DOM manipulation (right-click on the node you're interested in) - if the scripts are being inserted while the page is running, you could break at the very start of the page loading and then set a DOM breakpoint on the parent tag of where the script is being inserted.  Then, when the script tag is added, you'll get a break and a call stack.

Comment: Thanks, setting breakpoints and running through helped me locate where they were being added.